# how could two different View Controllers Communicate with each other

Tags: ios

I have an application with tab bar and 3 different View Controller. one of these imanage a UItableView that I designed through Interface Builder (storyboard) and I set the it's view controller class in the Inspector -> inspector identity -> and I set class field there, hence, I have no control when this view controller get instantiated, as it's done through storyboard when user click on tab bar. notice, i'm new to objective C and iOS programming.

the issue that I'm facing, i'm also using remote notification. hence, when I receive a remote notification message in "didReceiveRemoteNotification" in the AppDelgate class. I need to update UI interface (above ViewController), but the issue I don't have a reference (pointer) to this ViewController from my AppDelgate class ( or do I?). the problem this ViewController instantiated by storyboard nor programmatically, otherwise I could have kept a reference to it.

I did some reading and I understand I could do this communication via NSNotification, but I think this will be an overkill for a problem that maybe arise just because I'm new to this and I don't have full understanding of iOS development.

Thanks,

Comment: wall of text. Please use paragraphs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your app Delegate will have a window property which points to the apps window.

Window Property has a [-rootViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWindow_Class/UIWindowClassReference/UIWindowClassReference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIWindow/rootViewController) property/method.

For your Tab Based Application it would return you the TabViewController.

Each TabViewController have a method [-(NSArray *)viewControllers](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITabBarController/viewControllers) which returns the ViewControllers inside the Tab. These are arranged in the order.

To Access your applications AppDelegate use [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate]

Once you have these viewcontrollers you would know which all viewController these are since you have added it in the XIB files. and can perform your methods

Comment: Thanks ... I think this exactly, what i'm looking for; do you have an example so that I can follow?

Comment: -(UIViewControllerX *)viewControllerX 
{
        YourAppDelegate * appDelegate = (YourAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

       UITabViewController * tabController = [appDelegate.window rootViewController];

       NSArray * viewControllerArray = tabController.viewControllers;
return [viewControllerArray objectAtIndex:(X-1)];

}

Once you have the viewController you can perform the method

Comment: thanks ... I'm getting unknown type name UITabViewController??

Comment: I think you mean UITabBarViewController not UITabViewController, right?

Answer (score 14):

NSNotifications are easy to use and are probably the right solution.

In the app delegate that needs to send the message, just put:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"MyNotification" object:someObjectYouWantToPassCouldBeAppDelegateOrRemoteNotificationObjectOrAnything];
```

In the view controller that is receiving the message, put:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //you can add as many of these as you like to handle different notifications
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]  addObserver:self selector:@selector(handleNotification:) name:@"MyNotification" object:nil];
}

-(void)viewDidUnload
{
     //make sure you remove every observer you've added here 
     [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:@"MyNotification" object:nil];

     [super viewDidUnload];
}

-(void)dealloc
{
    //clean up in case viewDidUnload wasn't called (it sometimes isn't) 
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
    [super dealloc];
}

//use a different handler method for each notification
//the method name should match the selector in your observe call in viewDidLoad
-(void)handleNotification:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    WhateverClassOfObjectYouWerePassing *object = notification.object;

    //now you have a reference to the object that was passed from your app delegate
}
```

For different methods you want to call, just and a new notification name and a new handler method.

Comment: I've tweaked the example code slightly to make it clear that you can pass any object in the notification. If you need to pass additional objects, you can add an NSDictionary of extra data to the notification using the optional userInfo parameter in postNotificationName:object:userInfo:

Comment: Is it guarenteed that these are delivered in order? Example: if user updates a slider twice very quickly, slider posts an "on" and "off" notification, will they arrive in the correct order?

Comment: Notifications are delivered synchronously - there's no delay at all between the notification being sent and being received, it's just like calling a method except that there may be multiple recipients.

Comment: +1. After burning 4 hours attempting to accomplish the same task that op was doing, I saw your answer and had it working in 10 minutes.  Delegates + Protocols seem powerful, but Notifications do seem like a better fit for this particular task.

Answer (score 1):

**1. Communicate two ViewControllers**

If you want to communicate two ViewControllers, you should use [@protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithProtocols/WorkingwithProtocols.html) as Apple recommended:

---

ViewController1.h

---

```
 @interface ViewController1 : UIViewController<ViewController2Delegate, ViewController2DataSource>
@end
```

---

ViewController1.m

---

```
- (IBAction)goToViewController2:(id)sender{
    if(viewController2 == nil) {
        ViewController2 *viewController = [[ViewController2 alloc]
                                               initWithNibName:@"View2" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
        viewController2 = viewController;
    }
    //...
    viewController2.delegate = self;
    viewController2.dataSource = self;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController2 animated:YES];
}


- (NSString)viewController:(ViewController2 *)controller itemForSomethingAtIndex:(NSInteger)index{
    //Send to viewController2 what it needs
    return [items objectAtIndex: index];
}
- (void)viewController:(ViewController2 *)controller didFinishEnteringItem:(NSString *)item{
    //Handle the result from the viewController2
    NSLog(@"result: %@", item);
}
```

---

ViewController2.h

---

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


// Define your delegate methods to return items to the delegate of this viewController
@protocol ViewController2Delegate <NSObject>
    - (void)viewController:(ViewController2 *)controller didFinishEnteringItem:(NSString *)item;
@end

// Define your dataSource methods to send items from the dataSource to this viewController
@protocol ViewController2DataSource <NSObject>
    - (NSString)viewController:(ViewController2 *)controller itemForSomethingAtIndex:(NSInteger)index;
@end



@interface ViewController2 : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic) id <ViewController2Delegate> delegate;
@property (nonatomic) id <ViewController2DataSource> dataSource;

@end
```

---

ViewController2.m

---

```
#import "ViewController2.h"

@interface ViewController2 ()
@end

@implementation ViewController2

@synthesize //...;

- (void)someMethod {
    //Get someThing from controller1
    NSString *item = [dataSource viewController: self itemForSomethingAtIndex:0];

    //Return someThing to controller1
    [delegate viewController: self didFinishEnteringItem: item];
}
```

---

**2. Communicate backgroundTask with viewController**

If you want to communicate a background task or handle a push notification, use @NickLockwood's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9127852/2835520). But this dont gonna work if the viewController its not loaded. In this case you should handle that in the AppDelegate:

---

```
//Get the appDelegate instance
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
//And call your custom method to show what it needs
[appDelegate customMethod];
```

---

Your custom method should call controllers consecutevly like:

```
AppDelegate > RootController > ViewController1 > ViewController2 > myMethod 
//do something if viewController2 is visible to the user or push it before do something.
//if you use navigation controller, then you need to ask for the position and className
```