# How do i access an object on one view from a different view?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitabbarcontroller

I have a tab bar controller with two tabs:

- tabBar1View with a button named "openDifferentView" and a textfield
  "myvalue" with text "test"
- tabBar2View with a textfield named
  "txtInTab2"

When I tap on openDifferentView i want tabBar2View to show, and pass the value "test" (from `tabBar1View.myvalue.text`) to `txtInTab2` (in tabBar2View).

I get the view to show up using `[self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:1]` but I'm unsure how I can set the value of its textfield, from this view.

I thought this would be possible:

```
UIViewController *tab2;
tab2 = [self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1];
tab2.txtInTab2.text = "something"; //doesn't work
tab2.show; //don't know how to this
```

Edit: I have already added IBOutlet @property/@synthesize for the textfield in tabBar2View, and #import "tabBar2View.h" in tabBar1View.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UIViewController doesn't have a property called txtInTab2. txtInTab2 is a property you've added to your own UIViewController subclass (which you've called TabBar2View).

The code is basically right, but you need to define tab2 as being whatever type of view controller it actually is. From your comments below, it's actually a navigation controller, so you'll need to do this:

```
#import "MyViewController.h"

UInavigationController *tab2;
tab2 = [self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1];

//now lets get the frontmost view controller in the navigation controller
//which will (hopefully) be your custom view controller class
TabBar2View *viewController = (TabBar2View *)tab2.topViewController;

//now before we set the label, we need to make sure that the
//view controller's view has actually been loaded from its nib
//file. calling its view property forces it to load
[viewController view];

//now we can set the label
viewController.txtInTab2.text = @"something"; //this will work now
```

Then to actually show it, you need to do this via the tab bar controller, like this:

```
[self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:1]; //show the second tab
```

Comment: Ah, stupid mistake... But it crashes:
[UINavigationController txtInTab2]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x68b4dd0

Comment: It sounds like the View controller in your second tab is actually a UINavigationController containing your view controller. I've updated my answer.

Comment: That worked perfect! And i even understand it perfectly. Thanks a lot! But i guess i still should look into delegates, if i understand correctly, that is the preffered way if i'm dealing with a lot of passing of data between views?

Comment: Actually in a case like this, NSNotifications are probably the way to go. They let you pass messages by "broadcasting" them so that any class that is interested can listen out for the messages. That way you don't need to get a reference to one class from another one. Google NSNotificationCenter for examples.

Comment: I just answered a question about communicating between views using NSnotifications. You may find my answer useful for future reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9127696/how-could-two-different-view-controllers-communicate-with-each-other/9127852#9127852

Answer (score 0):

You need to use delegates. I think [this](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/54859-sharing-data-between-view-controllers-other-objects.html) will give you a good help about how to get started

Comment: Thanks, i'll look into that. But are you sure what i'm trying to achieve is impossible without a delegate class?

Comment: No i don't say it is a must. I once needed something like this, I used 'NSUserDefaults' klass to save the data in the first class and used that saved content to display-use in the second class(i mean in diffrent classes which had their own views). If this sounds sensible, please let me now and i shall edit my answer with some code for you