# dismissViewControllerAnimated not passing back data to vc1

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have vc1 and vc2. I need vc2 to set a vc1's variable when vc2 is dismissed.

This is relevant code in vc1.h

```
- (IBAction)btnclick:(id)sender;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *mystr;
```

This is relevant code in  vc1.m

```
- (IBAction)btnclick:(id)sender {
    UIStoryboard * storyboard = self.storyboard;
    NSString * storyboardName = [storyboard valueForKey:@"name"];
    //In storyboard I named vc2 "ctrl2" as identifier 
    ViewController2 *temp = 
    [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:storyboardName bundle:nil]     instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ctrl2"];
    [self presentViewController:temp animated:YES completion:NULL];
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    NSLog(@"In viewWillAppear mystr is %@", self.mystr);
}

- (void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSLog(@"my str is %@", self.mystr);
}
```

This is relevant code in vc2.h

```
@class ViewController;

- (IBAction)btnclkd:(id)sender;
@property(nonatomic, weak)ViewController *vc1Obj;
```

This is relevant code in vc2.m

```
- (IBAction)btnclkd:(id)sender {
    self.vc1Obj.mystr = @"test";
    NSLog(@"setting mystr from v2");
    [self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

viewDidLoad in vc1 dont get triggered when vc2 is dismessed. So I have tried to log both in viewDidAppear and viewWillAppear.
In both case, mystr is ALWAYS null. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Take a look to this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24098762/2835520)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me as though you are never setting the `vc2.vc1Obj`.

My recommendation would be that in vc1's `- (IBAction)btnclick:(id)sender;` you do this:

```
- (IBAction)btnclick:(id)sender 
{
    //    in storyboard I named vc2 "ctrl2" as identifier 
    ViewController2 *temp = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ctrl2"];
    temp.vc1Obj = self;
    [self presentViewController:temp animated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```