# Xcode Update View Controller UIImage from AppDelegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I want to call a function from `AppDelegate` in `ViewController.m`. I will access the function well done, but the View Controller function is not working.

In `AppDelegate.m` file I have:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "UserList.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    return YES;
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{
    NSString *UserName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"] objectForKey:@"from"]];
    if (application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateActive) 
    {
        UserList *ul = [[UserList alloc] init];
        [ul AddUserWhenNotExists:UserName];
    }
}
```

`UserList.m` file of view controller:

```
#import "UserList.h"

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
- (void)accessFromAppDelegate
{
    UIImageView *setting =[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,20,61,60)];
    setting.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"setting_icon.png"];
    [setting setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

    UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap =  [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(SettingClick:)];
    [singleTap setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
    [setting addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
    [self.view addSubview:setting];

}
```

In `UserList` of view controller does not append `setting_icon.png`. Is my code wrong? Please help.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to use NSNotificationCenter: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsnotificationcenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html

You can use it to tell your UIViewController when something happens. Here is some example code: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/9127852/2661880